# Problem with apache 2.4.6 on ubuntu 13.10 no rewrite for wordpress links

Tags: localhost, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

My rewrite was working well until i updated my apache and than went dead .

**My 000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory "/var/www">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride FileInfo
   # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
   Require all granted
</Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I would like to use if possible the default localhost and have mod rewrite
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you provide your rewrite rules? Do you use .htaccess for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been having a similar problem with my localhost. Check `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` Change:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Check Here for more details:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151875